# An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Identity 'ap-south-1:sadf'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am getting ResourceNotFoundException when I call GetCredentialsForIdentity using IdentityId and Logins

```
client_identify = boto3.client('cognito-identity', region_name=POOL_REGION)
logins = {}
logins[
    "cognito-idp." + POOL_REGION + ".amazonaws.com/" + USER_POOL
] = id_token;
print(logins, IDENTITY_POOL_ID)
res = client_identify.get_credentials_for_identity(
  IdentityId=IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
  Logins=logins
)
```

Error I am getting here is:
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred
(ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Identity
enter code here'ap-south-1:asdfadsfasdfsdafdsadfasdfasd'

When I try to do with javascript it's working absolutely fine.

Is there any solution in python?

Comment: Are you sure you've specified correct `IDENTITY_POOL`?

Comment: Yeah. I am using IDENTITY_POOL_ID

Comment: But in the code there is no `IDENTITY_POOL_ID`. Instead there is `IDENTITY_POOL` or `POOL_ID`? These are all different?

Comment: I have update question please check.

Comment: I am following this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_credentials_for_identity to implement. Here they mentioned 'IdentityId' but I am providing 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IDENTITY_POOL_ID` and `IDENTITY_ID` are two **different things**. Basically need to use [get_id](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_id) to obtain `IDENTITY_ID` from `IDENTITY_POOL_ID`.

Here is the code which I tested to be working:

```
import boto3  
                                                                                          
                                                
client_identify = boto3.client('cognito-identity')   
                                                  
IDENTITY_POOL_ID = 'us-east-1:xxxxx-3f18-41f9-b4a6-xxxxx' 


response = client_identify.get_id(
         IdentityPoolId=IDENTITY_POOL_ID
)  

print(response)


IDENTITY_ID = response['IdentityId']                                                                      

print(IDENTITY_ID)                             

res = client_identify.get_credentials_for_identity(
       IdentityId=IDENTITY_ID
)

print(res)
```

You need to adjust it to your requirements.

Comment: Thansk, I am doing almost same but don't have 'AccountId'. This all I doing to integrated my system with third party.

Comment: This is the data which I got from my third party to integrate 
{
        "user":"AAAAAAAA",
        "password":"BBBBBBB",
        "userPool":"CCCCCCCCC",
        "appClient":"DDDDDDDD",
        "identityPool":"EEEEEEEEE",
        "region":"FFFFFF",
        "basePath":"https://testapi.test.co.in/test/"
    }

Comment: `AccountId (string) ` is optional in `get_id`. Thus you many not need it.

Comment: Thanks, U Helped me allot. I thought AccountId mandatory

Comment: @Kanna No problem. Glad I could help :-)